# Dynamic Load ListView Template from .ascx

Tags: asp.net, listview, itemtemplate

I use this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2008/07/26/dynamically-loading-listview-templates.aspx article as example for dynamic loading templates(from .ascx files).

this is author code:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ListView1.LayoutCreated += new EventHandler(ListView1_LayoutCreated);
        ListView1.LayoutTemplate = LoadTemplate("LayoutTemplate.ascx");
        ListView1.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("ItemTemplate.ascx");
    }

    void ListView1_LayoutCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //remove the layout template
        ListView1.Controls.RemoveAt(0);

        //recreate it
        Control newLayoutContainer = new Control();
        ListView1.LayoutTemplate.InstantiateIn(newLayoutContainer);
        var userControl = newLayoutContainer.Controls[0];
        userControl.ID = "MyLayout";
        ListView1.Controls.Add(newLayoutContainer);
    }
```

it gives error:

**An ItemTemplate must be defined on ListView 'ListView1'.**

after postback.

What's wrong? Should I create ListView every time I postback ( http://forums.asp.net/p/1305569/2558209.aspx )?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your problem do the following :

```
<script runat="server">

   protected void ListView_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

         ListView1.ItemTemplate = LoadTemplate("ItemTemplate2.ascx");

    }

</script>

<asp:ListView ....   OnInit="ListView_Init">
```